How avoid loading micro partitions where only want the latest entry per customer
Imagine I have a vast table of customers, orders, for arg sake trillions of customers each with trillions of orders. I store customer ID, order ID, order time (which has no dupe times per customer). My table is clustered by customer ID, order Time.
I want to get the latest order for each customer and minimise loading micro partitions. As far as I can tell I can Rank ordered by time descending, take Rank zero, but that will first go unnecessarily over all orders. If I use Qualify that applies after windowing fn completes. If i use LIMIT that can’t be applied per customer ID.
So how do I optimise this query?

I don't think you can do better by changing your query in this case, but your table clustering sounds expensive to me.  I'd recommend clustering by order time, customer id, but mostly because you're likely spending a lot when you load new data.  It may also help your query, but not likely by much.

If the query that you are performing is a common query against that table, you might want to consider creating a dynamic table with that logic applied.  That table will incrementally get updated as new data is added, and then queries against that table will be direct selects on a much smaller dataset.  However, you'd have to evaluate the cost of maintaining the dynamic table compared to the queries being executed against the larger table.

I assume you work in a bank ;)
You can leverage clustering and filtering efficiently
A) Clustering your table by customer_id and order_time ensures that the data is physically organized to minimize scanning unnecessary micro-partitions.
Use CLUSTER BY (customer_id, order_time DESC) so that the latest order for each customer is more accessible. The descending order ensures the most recent orders are at the start of each cluster.
B) Use row-level filtering with QUALIFY:
Instead of ranking all rows, use the QUALIFY clause with ROW_NUMBER() directly. Snowflake processes the QUALIFY clause more efficiently by applying it after filtering and clustering.
SELECT 
    customer_id,
    order_id,
    order_time
FROM orders
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_time DESC) = 1;


I mentioned Qualify above. My understanding of “ In the execution order of a query, QUALIFY is therefore evaluated after window functions are computed” is that all the ranks are computed and the Qualify is applied. If not this will provide the right solution. Sounds like needs a test.

How often do you need to run the query? If the concern of high compute cost comes from running the queries frequently, you may want to consider adopting an incremental computation model to minimize unnecessary scanning of the entire dataset after adopting clustering as other user explained.
Consider creating a Materialized View (MV) or a "latest order" view. This view can be incrementally updated to reflect the latest order for each customer as new orders arrive, leveraging the clustering by customer ID and order Time.
eg:
Use a query to create a materialized view or equivalent mechanism in your database to define the Latest Order View, something like:
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW latest_orders AS
SELECT 
    customer_id,
    MAX(order_time) AS latest_order_time
FROM 
    orders
GROUP BY 
    customer_id;

This view will store the latest order_time for each customer_id. The clustering by customer_id and order_time helps optimize the query.
Once you have the latest_order_time for each customer, you can use it to retrieve other details of the latest order with a join:
SELECT 
    o.customer_id,
    o.order_id,
    o.order_time
FROM 
    orders o
JOIN 
    latest_orders lo
ON 
    o.customer_id = lo.customer_id 
    AND o.order_time = lo.latest_order_time;

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/views-materialized
